# What does the bool in Control.ResumeLayout do?

Tags: .net, winforms

[Control.ResumeLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k76wfs.aspx) has a bool that the MSDN states

> true to execute pending layout requests; otherwise, false.

which does not explain well what that means, and what the consequences of being set to `true` or `false` would be. The remarks section also appears to have contradictory information (looks like someone copied and pasted from the no parameter version then added the second sentence)

> Calling the ResumeLayout method forces an immediate layout if there are any pending layout requests. When the performLayout parameter is set to true, an immediate layout occurs if there are any pending layout requests.

I think if it is set to `true` it will immediately perform any layout changes, but I don't understand what happens when it is `false`. Will the layout changes just be deferred till later, are they ever done, why would you ever need to use `false`?

So what is the difference between passing `true` or `false` to the function?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct (and I agree that the text looks to have copy-paste problems).

If passing `true` (or using the overload without arguments) two things happen:

1. If any layout-triggering events have been suppressed during the layout-suspended period, layout is performed immediately.
2. Future layout triggers result in layout being performed.

If passing `false`, then #1 does not happen.